# GetElementsByTagName which is not case sensitive?

Tags: xml, xmldocument, case-sensitive, getelementsbytagname

i'm using GetElementsByTagName to extract an element from an xml.
GetElementsByTagName is case sensitive - it throws an exception if the node name is 'PARAMS' instead of 'Params'.
i dont want that , can i use a different way in XMLDocument so it wont be case sensitive ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the DOM specifies case-sensitivity - although I know some libraries (eg. one of PHPs) don't always behave this way. XML itself is always case-sensitive. Knowing which language you are using would be helpful. More background information would be helpful. What is the problem you are actually looking to solve? See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: thakn you,

I'm writing in C#. I'm receiving the XML by a WCF service. when i get the XML i dont want the code to fail just because one of the XML nodes is 'name' instead of 'Name' or even 'NAME', when i analyze it using GetElementsByTagName.

Comment: But why? Since XML is case-sensitive, nobody should ever give you a document with those characteristics. It's a malformed document if they do - and you should probably just handle the exception and tell them off!

Comment: Since XML is case-sensitive, it seems there could be elements with TagName="PARAMS", and other elements with TagName="Params" (even though one or the other may be incorrect for your application. You should be able to do `nodeList1=document.getElementsByTagName("PARAMS")` to get a list of `<PARAMS ...>` nodes, and `nodeList2=document.getElementsByTagName("Params")` to get a list of `<Params ...>` nodes. It's unclear why you would be getting an error for either statement.

Answer (score 12):

Since my other answer was deemed 'not an answer', yet the answer is clearly *no*, let's try again with a more succinct and to the point post:

> can i use a different way in XMLDocument so it wont be case sensitive

No.

Now the questioner can improve his answer count and I won't have to question the sanity of moderators here.